# OrderBy() removes items from a query

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

I just discovered that in EF7 RC1 OrderBy() statement removes items from a query if navigation property is null.

```
var units = db.Units.Include(i => i.VehicleModel).OrderBy(u => u.VehicleModel.Displacement);
```

I have 23 items in db.Units, three of which have VehicleModel navigation property set to null. The resulted *units* will have only 20 items.

Is that a bug or by design? How would I change the code for the items not to disappear?

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
.OrderBy(u => u.VehicleModel == null ? 0 : u.VehicleModel.Displacement)
```

Comment: There is compilation error "Operator || cannot be applied to operands of type 'bool' and 'init'

Comment: It compiles now, but the result is the same - missing items in the list.

Comment: What works is using ToList() before your suggestion. I.e.: .ToList().OrderBy(u => u.VehicleModel == null ? 0 : u.VehicleModel.Displacement)

Comment: That then means the query is not being executed by the database and instead is being executed in memory... (well, the ordering part of the query anyway)